# IP forwarding, (packet redirect)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, command, ip

I'm looking for a way to forward all the packets coming to a 192.151.155.3:25550 to 192.151.155.2:25570

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.151.155.3 --dport 25550 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.151.155.2:25570
```

I tried using the command above which did not work. Is there's another way of doing this? or I'm I using the command currectly?

Also how would I make all the outgoing packets from 192.151.155.2:25570 go through 192.151.155.3:25550

thanks in advance!

Comment: For the question "how to make all outgoing packets from 192.151.155.2:25570 go through 192.151.155.3:25550" try `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.151.155.2 -p tcp --sport 25570 -j SNAT --to-source 192.151.155.3:25550`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rinetd` to redirects TCP connections from one IP address and port to another.

1. Install rinetd

   *sudo apt-get install rinetd*
2. Edit /etc/rinetd.conf and include below line. This is the rinetd configuration file.

   *192.151.155 25550 192.151.155.2 25570*
3. Restart rinetd to apply new configuration change

   *sudo /etc/init.d/rinetd restat*

Try this iptable command:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 192.151.155.3 --dst 192.168.1.5 -p tcp --dport 25550 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 25570
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rein` to redirects TCP connections from one IP address and port to another. Is very intuitive, simple to use.

https://github.com/firstboot/rein

linux:

```
cd ~
wget http://note.youdao.com/yws/public/resource/b1e1ad270ba1b1af97ebdf3e2c8b7403/xmlnote/82E2CC3FF2744238B6AF36346298E5E5/27082 -O rein.zip
unzip rein.zip
mv rein-*-linux rein
chmod +x rein
./rein -e > rein.json
# modify rein.json for you
./rein -c rein.json
```

windows:

```
# unzip package, and rename
ren rein-1.0.3-amd64-win.exe rein.exe

# generate default conf 'rein.json'
# windows cmd 
./rein.exe -e > rein.json

# windows powershell
./rein.exe -e | out-file -encoding ascii rein.json
```